# Why do my $PATH and /etc/paths Differ?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mountain-lion, path

Typing `export $PATH` in Mountain Lion's Terminal returns

```
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin`
```

However, my /etc/paths file shows:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Is this a problem?

Comment: /usr/local/bin found twice??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly OK.

As you log in, your PATH is constructed from several different sources. Some are system wide, others are user specific: the `.profile` file in your home folder, for example, is a common way for adding paths to your PATH for your account only.

You can see that the paths from `/etc/paths` are still there, in the middle of your PATH but some stuff has been added. `/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin` for example has been added by macGPG2 when you installed it.

Comment: what's the order of loading those PATH?